# Dialogflow and Firebase - Iterate list of data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

Making a chatbot that recommends a movie based on genre and other factors. Trying to iterate through an object retrieved from a firebase realtime database in DialogFlow. I'm using forEach but when triggered it displays "Not Available".

Preferably, the function would display a random item from the list but I have not reached that part yet - any advice on this too would be appreciated.

Below is my code.

```
  function displayData(agent) {
      return ref.orderByChild("genre1").equalTo("Comedy").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
          let obj = {};
          obj = snapshot.val();
          obj.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              var childData = childSnapshot.val();
              agent.add(childData.name);
          });
      });
    }
```

Below is a sample database

```
{
  "movies" : {
    "movie1" : {
      "genre1" : "Sci-Fi",
      "genre2" : "Horror",
      "name" : "Alien",
      "rating" : 84,
      "year" : 1979
    },
    "movie2" : {
      "genre1" : "Comedy",
      "genre2" : "Parody",
      "name" : "Airplane",
      "rating" : 97,
      "year" : 1980
    },
    "movie3" : {
      "genre1" : "Comedy",
      "genre2" : "Teen",
      "name" : "Superbad",
      "rating" : 88,
      "year" : 2007
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The base problem is that the Dialogflow library requires you to return a Promise, however you're using the callback version of the call instead of the Promise version of the call.  You need to change this to something more like

```
  function displayData(agent) {
    return ref.orderByChild("genre1").equalTo("Comedy").on("child_added")
      .then( snapshot => {
        // Do something with the snapshot
      });
  }
```

(You probably also want to use `once("value")` instead of `on("child_added")`, since you don't need updates to be sent in realtime.)

While the `forEach()` is probably working correctly, there is a minor problem that not all agents will return all the text that has been `.add()`ed. So you probably only want to call `.add()` once.

Since you really only want once of these children, picked randomly, you can just treat this as a JavaScript object if you have enough memory. So you could just get the keys with `Object.keys(obj)`, pick one of the keys by random, and then get the full value of the result.